# Unable to start NextJS Dev server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have just started with NextJS. I created the new project using `npx create-next-app <app_name>`

When I tried starting the dev server using `npm run dev` the following error pops up.

Please help me with the error.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: `node -v && npm -v`

Comment: Update your Node.js version

Comment: Thank you all for the support. After updating the Node to latest version it started working fine.